# How do I set "button 2" of mouse to "show desktop"

Tags: mouse

My middle mouse button (the scroll wheel pressed down), after turning off the `gnome-tweak` middle click is paste, shows as `button 2` in `xev`:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4ee, subw 0x0, time 8879244, (79,71), root:(1759,879),
    state 0x10, button 2, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4ee, subw 0x0, time 8879452, (79,71), root:(1759,879),
    state 0x210, button 2, same_screen YES
```

It now functions in browsers to open links in a new tab. I want it to show the desktop.

I installed `wmctrl` and can `show desktop` by typing into terminal `wmctrl -k on`.  But I cannot figure out how to associate `button 2` with that command.

In Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom, adding the command works, but it is not possible to associate it with the button click.

In `dconf editor`, I tried using `xautomation` and the command `xte 'mouseclick 2'`, but that didn't work either (nor did `button 2` or `'button 2'` or `button2`.

Any idea what the correct binding is for `button 2` in `dconf editor` or how to get the `Settings` menu to accept it?

Comment: as the question got bumped to community I'm wondering if your question got answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't already, install xbindkeys:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Then we'll need to find out whats you mouse-button called (usually Button2, but we'll want to be sure).
write 
`xev |grep button` in terminal. A white window will appear. Do a middle click inside and read the output in terminal, eg:

```
 state 0x10, button 2, same_screen YES
state 0x210, button 2, same_screen YES
```

So for me its button 2.

Now write a default xbindkey-file with:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Edit the file with scratch or: `nano .xbindkeysrc`

Look if there's allready an entry for your middle button, edit it or make a new one as following:

```
#show desktop
"wmctrl -k on"
   b:2
```

Save the file. (with nano it's Ctrl+O).

Run xbindkey in terminal. If it's working add xbindkey to your startup-applications.